# java interface use with other projects

Tags: java

I'm trying to use a interface for several app.  I have one app doing the logic and another app receiving the logic (UDP connection) I don't have the slightist idea how to do this.

Simple example. 
app 1

interfaceApp.java

```
public interface interfaceApp {
int addNums(int a, int b);
}
```

logic.java

```
public class logic implements  interfaceApp {

@Override
public int addNums(int a, int b) {
    a = a + b;
return a;
}
```

I don't know what do do in the main activity
app 2
how can I call the method addNums?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a common java project, containing all the interfaces you want to share among the projects. From the concrete project you just reference the common one an then you can use those interfaces. 
Via Eclipse IDE you do the following:

1. Create a java project called "CommonXY" (or sth. else)
2. Creat the interaces and classes in "CommonXY"
3. From the concrete project: Properties -> Java Build Paths -> Projects -> Add -> Choose: CommonXY -> OK